# Prevent unnecessary chunk to load for a route in isomorphic app

Tags: reactjs, webpack, chunks, webpack-splitchunks, isomorphic

I am trying to do some bundling optimisation using webpack for isomorphic app,but am not able to avoid not needed chunk from loading for a route which doesn't require it.I would really appreciate some resource or solution you could point me to.

Ex: /home is the route
Expected: home.chunk.js to only load
Observation: home.chunk.js and home~details.chunk.js as well loading

I tried various webpack solutions and also tried code splitting but was unsuccessful.Below is the link for one of the resource.

https://medium.com/airbnb-engineering/server-rendering-code-splitting-and-lazy-loading-with-react-router-v4-bfe596a6af70

Comment: webpack's [optimization.chunkIDs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/#optimizationchunkids) is a good start.

Comment: Thanks jishan shaikh, trying to move to webpack 5 to use the optimization properly.